# Create win8.1 boot USB from temp boot environment?

Tags: windows-8.1

Need to create a Win 8.1 boot USB drive.  However don't have any native Win8.1 machines to run MS mediacreationtool.exe from, all Win8.1 environments I have available are virtualised.  Only native OS's we have are Server 2012, WinXP & various Linux.

So question is are there any Win8.1 run from DVD type environments available that I could boot to and run mediacreationtool.exe from there?

Comment: Eh? It runs fine on Server 2012, and it even runs in virtual machines, if you pass the USB device through.

Comment: Doesn't for me, mediacreationtool.exe returns error "This platform is not supported"

Comment: Also I have no "Enhanced Session Mode" available under Hyper-V settings so can't do USB passthrough that way.

Comment: Try using the [Windows USB/DVD Download Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/windows-usb-dvd-download-tool) instead.

Comment: Just tried that and it returns: "This application requires .Net framework 2.0"
Not sure I want to risk destabilizing the 2012 server by installing that.

Comment: If you have a 2012 server without 2.0 installed I'd argue stability is already an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer now found - create bootable USB manually and simply copy files there from the .iso, didn't realise that it was that simple

Would probably be more useful if I explained how:

- diskpart
- list disk
- select disk 2 - (USB drive)
- clean create partition
- primary select partition 1
- active
- format fs=ntfs
- exit
- XCopy {path to mounted .iso}*.* {drive letter of USB stick} /s/v